# Does the index of a curve determine the asymptotic behaviour of certain vector fields?

Tags: asymptotics, vector-fields

There are a collection $C$ of charges in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which cause an electric vector field $V$ to form. Each charge's contribution to $V$ follows the inverse-square law. Let $\gamma$ be a curve encolsing all charges and critical points (not at infinity is there is a critical point there).

Let the index of $\gamma$ on $V$ be $n$.

In the cases of $n=1$ and $n=2$, I have noticed the following, and am curious to see a proof or disproof of the general case

**The magnitude of the vectors in $V$ is asymptotically proportional to $r^{-1-n}$, where $r$ is the distance from the origin.**

Comment: There are a few things unclear in this question, at least for me. By using the variable $V$ an electric potential (scalar) is suggested; an electric vector field is usually denoted by $\vec{E}$ . "encolsing" must be "enclosing". What is "critical point"? "is" must be "if" at "is there is". At last, would you mind to write up the _definition_ of your "winding number"? Because I'm affraid I'm thinking of something quite different now.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Thanks. I've not got the time now, but by Saturday I'll have edited it.

Comment: @Alyosha Could you please explicitly define what you mean by "winding number of a vector field"? As far as I know, there's no such thing. Under the usual definition, winding numbers are properties *of* curves, not properties of vector fields on curves.

Comment: @DavidH Let $v(p)$ be the vector associated with the point $p$. I define winding number to be the number of anticlockwise revolutions $\frac{v(p)}{|v(p)|}$ makes as $p$ moves along $\gamma$ in a closed loop. What you're referring to seems to be the case when $v(p)=p$.

Comment: I think Needham calls it the winding number, I'd be happy to know the proper name for this.

Comment: @Alyosha Ok, I get the gist of what you're trying to describe, but how do you calculate it? How would you write  the winding number of a vector field in terms of a line integral?

Comment: @DavidH

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\gamma} \frac{v(p)_x}{|v(p)|^2}dy- \frac{v(p)_y}{|v(p)|^2}dx.$$

Comment: @DavidH I think I'm talking about the index of the curve, sorry for the confusion of terminology (regardless, I'm talking about the thing Needham is talking about in Visual Complex Analysis, page $\approx 498$).